# Ruby on Rails simple_form prepend $ before input with custom label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

I'm trying to prepend a `$` in front of one of my fields and I was able to successfully do so, but without a custom label. This is the code that works:

```
= f.input :amount do
    $
    = f.input_field :amount, :label => false, :hint => false, :wrapper => false
```

This leads me to two confusing points. 1) Why does a label still appear when `:label => false`? and 2) why does this fail if I change it to:

```
= f.input :amount do
    $
    = f.input_field :amount, label: 'This is my label', :hint => false, :wrapper => false
```

When I change the label to my custom label the `$` moves above the label instead of in front of the field. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing

```
= f.input :amount do
  $
  = f.input_field :amount, label: 'This is my label', :hint => false, :wrapper => false
```

This generates html

```
$
<label for="amount">This is my label</label>
<input id="amount" name=" " type="text" />
```

I'm not sure but i think *simple_form is applying a css of display:block* on your labels as from [here](http://www.w3resource.com/html/HTML-block-level-and-inline-elements.php) labels are inline elements

I think all you need is some css magic to fix your issue

```
= f.input :amount do
  = f.input_field :amount, label: 'This is my label', :hint => false, :wrapper => false
  %span.dollar &#36;
```

and then on your input field use this css:

```
#input_id{
  //here your input_id would be something like resource_amount you can check it in developer console to be sure
  display:inline-block;
}

.dollar{
  float: left;
}
```

[**`JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpaw7/)

Comment: Would that not simply display the $ in front of the label? That's not what I'm trying to do, I want the label to appear above the input field but I want the $ to appear directly in front of the field itself.

Comment: @haye321 you want $ to be in front of your input field?

Comment: Yes, and with the first snippet in my question I accomplish that. My question is why can I not ALSO include a custom label. It seems that I need to choose one or the other.

Comment: I tried adding a class to all fields this would apply to with `wrapper_html: { class: 'dollar_field' }` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: wrapper_html would apply class to wrapper of input and label, it wont apply that class to input field

Comment: @haye321 if you'll inspect your element with firebug you'll see that your input will have a class of something like `resource_amount` so if your form is for person resource then that input will have an id `person_amount`

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, unfortunately I am back to the `$` displaying above the label again, not in front of the field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56367/discussion-between-mandeep-and-haye321).